# how to download a package with all required dependencies?

Tags: 10.04, installation, sudo

I want download ghc6. But, when I type

```
   sudo apt-get install ghc6 
   sudo apt-get -f install ghc6
   sudo apt-get install --reinstal ghc6
```

it gives same error:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   ghc6: Depends: libgmp3-dev but it is not installable
         Depends: libffi-dev but it is not installable
         Depends: libbsd-dev but it is not installable
 E: Broken packages
```

How can I fix that OR How can I install ghc6 to my desktop

ubuntu 10.04

EDIT :

```
apt-cache policy ghc6 libgmp3-dev; apt-cache show ghc6 libgmp3-dev


ghc6:

 Installed: (none)

 Candidate: 6.12.1-12

Version table:
 6.12.1-12 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Packages

libgmp3-dev:  
Installed: (none)  
Candidate: (none)
Version table:
Package: ghc6
Priority: optional
Section: universe/devel
Installed-Size: 378532
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Kari Pahula <kaol@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 6.12.1-12
Replaces: ghc6-doc (= 6.12.1-8), haddock
...    
Conflicts: ghc4 (<= 4.08.1-4), haddock
Breaks: cabal-install (<< 0.8.0), ghc6-doc (<= 6.12.1-8), haskell-devscripts (<<     0.6.19)
Filename: pool/universe/g/ghc6/ghc6_6.12.1-12_amd64.deb
...
Description: GHC - the Glasgow Haskell Compilation system
...
additional documentation can be found in the `haskell-doc' package.
 Alternatively, there is an online version at
 http://haskell.org/onlinereport/.
Homepage: http://haskell.org/ghc/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu


sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev libffi-dev libbsd-dev
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: 1. Check if the ghc6 and libgmp3-dev come from the ubuntu official repositories and not a third party repository: `apt-cache policy ghc6 libgmp3-dev; apt-cache show ghc6 libgmp3-dev` 2. Check why the 3 packages are not installable by installing them: `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev libffi-dev libbsd-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the dependencies listed [here](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/haskell-platform.xhtml), then you can build from source.

or try this

Update the package index:
 `sudo apt-get update`
Install ghc6-prof deb package:
 `sudo apt-get install ghc6-prof`

try this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed)

Comment: for sudo apt-get install haskell-platform error : sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: for website, not found

Comment: sudo apt-get install ghc6-prof
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: sorry for broken link now it will work , and some where u r using your dpkg . kill all dpkg try `killall -w aptget`

Comment: How to kill all dpkg ?

Comment: or if that doesn't work try this `sudo dpkg --configure -a` after that follow my answer

Comment: Killing `dpkg` may result in a need for reboot due to locking issues.

Comment: @Gaurav_Java , killall -w aptget : no process found

Comment: sudo apt-get install haskell-platform : E: Couldn't find package haskell-platform

Comment: sudo apt-get installghc6-prof : The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ghc6-prof: Depends: ghc6 (= 6.12.1-12) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

Comment: `sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock` or this will help

Comment: @Gaurav_Java, I did sudo fuser .. , what should I do next ? ( it emits no error )

Comment: follow all steps one by one

Comment: @Gaurav_Java, nothing changed, same errors

Comment: go to this [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed)

Comment: @Gaurav_Java, fixed, THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS